# INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY in Android studio 2.4 preview 7

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.4 preview 7 version. But, when I build debug apk and install via adb command or put apk file in sdcard of device it always gives me same error "App not installed" in any of android phone. I have got **INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY** error in Android Logcat every time at the time of installation in any android device.

Comment: I'm having same issue and not finding any solution to run my application through preview version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you [analyze your apk file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html) you'll see the problem easily - namely that when building the project with the mentioned Android Studio version, the Gradle plugin is automatically injecting an `android:testOnly=true` to the final `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the output apk.

You can read more about this property and what it's used for [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#testOnly).

To workaround this problem - you can still install the app using this command:

```
adb install -t debug.apk
```

If you want to build a signed `release` version of your app (e.g. for publishing the Play Store), you can always do so via `Build -> Generate Signed APK`. The result is an apk without the mentioned property and can be installed on any device.

If you want a bit of context why this property is injected, perhaps check [THIS](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37325241) and [THIS](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37150097) issues on the AOSP bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if we want to generate debug apk that generates from Build -> Build Apk(s) using this debug apk is install on any device.

Comment: You still can use the debug apk on any device, only that installation should be done via `adb` with the command I mentioned above :( That's indeed annoying (as Dropbox, email, etc channels can't be used to send the apk around). Hopefully that's not a final thing and will be changed in the stable release.