# There is a problem installing an unsigned APK on my device

Tags: android, apk

The problem is that I create an unsigned APK file from the Gradle of my Kotlin project in Android Studio, and up to this point there is no problem.

It is built in this path:

```
MyProject\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

I then proceed to share it (Google Drive, GitHub, messaging apps, email...) so that I can download and install it on my phone.

The problem is that when I go to install it (unknown sources allowed), it tells me that the app has not been installed, without any error messages or anything.

I have tried creating an empty project and following these steps, and this allows me to install it without any problems.

I have attached the directory tree of my project:

[image: directory tree of my project]

When installing the APK via adb I get the error

```
adb: failed to install app-debug.apk. Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI)
```

Comment: Is there another version of the app installed already on phone?

Comment: Debug APK files are not unsigned but usually signed using the user's debug key. Android doe snot allow installation of unsigned APK files. If you want to know why an APK file could not be installed try to install it on a phone with Android Debug Bridge enabled and use the command `adb install app-debug.apk` then you will get an error message you can work with.

Comment: @Robert I have tried creating an empty project and following these steps, and this allows me to install it without any problems.
The problem is that when I do it with my project it gives me this error.

Comment: Then you may have really selected the unsigned APK file which can not be installed. Use Android Studio and use the function "Build APK".

Comment: @Robert I have done this. I tried creating the unsigned and signed APK with a new project. Both let me install. When I do it with my project it won't let me. Could there be some leftover file conflicts?

Comment: Could be anything. Please use `adb install` to install the APK file that does not work and include the  command and it's output into your question.

Comment: @Robert
Here is the output of the installation:
https://prnt.sc/sgH3Ksjy1lvu

Comment: Please do not use screen shots terminal output is text, just copy and paste it into your question. The output shows that you selected the wrong APK, may be it is an intermediate build, not a full build. execute `./gradlew assembleDebug` to get a full debug APK file.

Comment: I got this output when using that command:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 26s
35 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 28 up-to-date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253300/discussion-between-lmbdr-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note:

- Your app is not "unsigned", it is signed with a debug key, and it is marked as a "test app" (an attribute is set by Gradle in the AndroidManifest.xml).
- Android framework does not allow the installation of a test app unless the installer allows it. With `adb`, you could allow a test app to be installed by passing the flag `-t` ([source](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#move))

Unfortunately, the installer built in Android does not support the installation of test apps AFAIK. See [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY in Android studio 2.4 preview 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980732/install-failed-test-only-in-android-studio-2-4-preview-7)

You can choose to either using `adb -t`, test APKs signed with release keys or use other testing frameworks (e.g. Firebase).

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for your detailed answer.
It is not marked as a "test app" in the AndroidManifest. And when I try to install with ".\platform-tools\adb.exe install -t app-debug.apk" I get a console "Success" but the installed application does not appear on the device.

Comment: What confuses me is that test apps usually have a different name like `app-debug-androidTest.apk`. Is it possible that AS uses "test apks" for APK files designed to incremental updating a debug app at run-time?

Comment: How did you determine that it's not marked as a "test app" in the AndroidManifest? This is an attribute that Android Gradle plugin automatically sets when you build as a debug build (whether it's an incremental build or not).